# VMware Fusion set host-only (aka private to my Mac) IP address / network?

Tags: network, security, virtualization, vmware

I am coming from VMware Workstation on Windows to VMware Fusion on Mac. In VMware Workstation it's possible to configure the host-only ip address / network in the network editor, in VMware Fusion it's not possible in the network editor. So, how can I change the host-only ip address / network in VMware fusion?

Also, if I currently check the ip of vmnet1, it's in the range of my normal Mac IP, like on a bridged network. Isn't that simply wrong / bad? Wouldn't that allow services on the host-only network to be available from outside my Mac?

**Update**

I am using `VMware Fusion Professional Version 11.5.2 (15794494)`

Screenshot of Settings -> Network
(as one can see, there is not network configuration possible for "private to my mac" (the blue selected item on the left)
[image]

Comment: I am able to do that on a wide variety of macOS and VMWare fusion versions. Are you able to upload a screen shot or perhaps list the versions of your software. If I have one that matches, I could show you the settings where I make the change. I don't think it matters, but if you have Fusion Pro or non - that does enable some extra features as well.

Comment: Have a look at: [Modifying the DHCP settings of vmnet1 and vmnet8 in Fusion (1026510)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1026510)

Comment: @bmike I updated my post, could you have a look at it / post a screenshot where you can change it? to user3439894: thanks, will have a look at this tomorrow!

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?  I am running into the same question/issue at the moment with VMFusion M1 Preview.  I cannot find a setting to specify the host's (ie the Mac) address, so I have no way specify a static IP address for the VM guest to use to connect back to the host (Mac)

Comment: @EricB. Actually I don't remember, I switched back to windows. Maybe check the link provided by user3439894

Comment: Thanks; I checked the link - but it only identifes how to modify the DHCP settings.  I'm looking to specify the host address.  Was hoping to find a solution lurking here somewhere, but looks like no one really deals with that.  Surprised that it is one thing that Windows does better/easier than the Mac. ;)